# Why does ARC make my app so slow?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I am trying to convert my app to ARC but when I do it slows down by a factor of 5 :(

In my graph view I have this block of code that iterates over all points:

```
            NSLog(@"%f", CACurrentMediaTime());
            for (NSUInteger xIndex = firstXValueOnScreen; xIndex <= lastXValueOnScreen; xIndex++)
            {
                float value = 5; //This used to call a function to get the value but I took out the function call to better demonstrate that this seems to be just a general slowdown...

                if (extremesUninitialized)
                {
                    yMax = value;
                    yMin = value;
                    extremesUninitialized = NO;
                }
                else
                {
                    yMax = MAX(yMax, v,alue);
                    yMin = MIN(yMin, value);
                }
            }
            NSLog(@"%f", CACurrentMediaTime());
```

Before ARC this block executes in about .01 seconds. Then, I use the ARC converter, which happily converts my code to ARC without any complaints. After this I run the same code under the same circumstances and get a result of .05 seconds! It's slowed down by a multiple of 5... So I restored my old project from a snapshot, so no more ARC, and did the test like 10 times and consistently got a result of .01 seconds. Then I converted it back to ARC and consistently got .05 seconds. XCode isn't giving me any clues here as to why this is happening... But the rest of my code is slowing too. What could be going on?

Comment: You really shouldn't be using ARC, especially if you're a beginner.

Comment: This is just pure C, so ARC shouldn't make a difference here. So I'd be very surprised if this code was actually running slower. For a better test, you should run the above code more than once (eg 1000 times in a loop) so your result is more accurate. Also are all the variables you reference above just local, or are some ivars? And @H2CO3, that is nonsense, ARC is meant to make things easier - so it is fine for beginners.

Comment: Wut?  ARC is exactly appropriate for beginners!  That is why it is the default for new projects and exactly why the analyzer, compiler and rest of the tool chain has been optimized around ARC.

Comment: What differences does Time Profiler show between this block of code with and without ARC enabled? Like pheelicks, I find it highly suspicious that a block of code with no Objective-C objects visible within it would at all be affected by enabling ARC.

Comment: @bbum "ARC is exactly appropriate for beginners! That is why it is the default for new projects" - that's just nonsense, maybe ARC is appropriate for senior developers, but surely not for beginners. Who the hell wants to explain all those `__bridge_transfer` casts to a beginner, when you could just say that "you retain when you need an object and you release when you don't need it anymore"? Far simpler. Also, beginners absolutely **need to** learn manual memory management, because ARC is not a silver bullet, and one **still** has to worry about managing memory even with ARC enabled.

Comment: @H2CO3 I wouldn't exactly call `__bridge_transfer` a beginner oriented topic in the first place.... And having taught Objective-C programming off and on for 20+ years, I am quite confident in the claim that manual retain/release is a lot more difficult for new programmers to grasp than "retain when you want it, release when you don't need it anymore".   Certainly, understanding the ins and outs of retain/release/autorelease is important in the long run.

Comment: @H2CO3 Technically correct, but how students feel is important. ARC connects theory and practice by enabling students to write apps earlier. Motivation and joy instruct the brain to pay more attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can only be a handful of options - it must be one of these:

1) your old code uses the optimizer at say -Os and the new code does not (so, you should be testing with "Release") not "Debug" configuration.

2) the value of (lastXValueOnScreen - firstXValueOnScreen), ie the range you are doing, is different (for who knows what reason, you would have to do some searching)

3) There is some background task - some thread - that is running amuck when you enabled ARC but its not there normally.

So some ideas on how to find this:

1) double check the Scheme configure setting in both, make sure its Release (not sure if ARC runs slower in Debug or not, but Debug for sure slower than Release).

2) Add these two values to your log statement above the for loop.

3) Move this whole chunk of code to your appDelegateLaunched method, before you do anything else , or even better put it in an "+(void)initialize" method in appDelegate (so it runs before any of your other code). Hard code large balues for your two variables.

Every single doc I've read on ARC says its faster; every Apple engineer says its faster; my experience is its faster.

Comment: The problem wasn't one of these but as far as what it could have possibly been this is a great answer. I'm still not entirely sure what the problem was but it has something to do with c data structures, maybe with the memcopy function. I went back and forth only ARCing certain files until I isolated which file, when ARCed, slowed down the app, and that file contains a class which relies heavily on C arrays and such.

Comment: Well, I just cannot understand how a bunch of C code could cause this. The only thing ARC is doing different is managing your retain/release/autorelease pools. Why don't you stick those timing logs in various places and try to see whats going on. If something is getting released prematurely then reinstantiated that for sure be a problem. I've been soooo happy using ARC now for over a year!

Answer (score 7):

I would be interested in seeing the problematic file.   In any case, you can always turn on ARC for everything, but leave it off for any problematic files (after performance optimization).  This is how we've built a bunch of stuff at Apple.

We generally turn on ARC for a whole project, then turn it off for specific files.  Any file that has it turned off gets this:

```
#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
#error This file should not be built with ARC until blah-blah-blah is fixed.
#endif
```

Comment: An addition: forcing ARC on or off for specific files is part of the builds settings of the target in Xcode. You can use the flags `-fno-objc-arc` to disable ARC and `-fobj-arc` (iirc) to enable ARC.